# How to return a Set in Java

Tags: java, methods, return, hashset

I have a class, `classA`, that has a constructor which uses objects from another class, `classB`. I use these objects of `classB` to form a set in `classA`.
Now, I have a method in `classA` that is setup to return the elements of the set created in the constructor.

This is where my issue is: I can't figure out the correct syntax to return the set elements.

This is my code:

```
package testing;
import java.util.*;

public class classA {

    public classA(classB x, classB y) {
        Set<classB> setElements = new HashSet<classB>();
        setElements.add(x);
        setElements.add(y);

    public set<classB> getElements() {
        return setElements; //THIS IS WHERE MY ERROR IS. HOW DO I RETURN A SET?
```

Comment: Do you come from javascript by chance ?

Comment: No, this is my first foray into the Java world. I have some experience in C, Python and a  couple other random languages but :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scope matters. You restricted the scope of your set to constructor. Make it an instance member. You are able to return it then.

```
 Set<classB> setElements = new HashSet<classB>();
 public classA(classB x, class B y) {
        setElements.add(x);
        setElements.add(y);
```

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I was doing wrong. Thank you for the help! I'll accept this as an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Happy coding. Mark it as answer if you found it helpful.